# SQL Server Full-Text Indexing can search Excel files in my table, but how can I extract the actual matching text from the Excel file?

Tags: sql, contains

My query is like this

```
select * 
from NAttachment 
where Contains(FileData, '"0412*"')
```

The result is like this:

[image]

The file is actually an Excel file, after opening file, I use <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> key to search for "0412", but cannot find any, not mention word starting with "0412".

My question is how SQL returns with a row where the column `FileData` doesn't include a word starting with "0412"?

Comment: Your `FileData` column looks like a Hex-encoded binary data. You're querying the hex string, not the actual file contents.

Comment: Maybe it is in a formula that doesn't show in the search function of Excel.

Comment: Thank Dai, Janez, and Jorge.

Comment: the excel file includes a column username with GUID format, and column first_name and last_name with chinese character. when I tried to use query    select * from NAttachment  where Contains(FileData, '"644dbf5f0415*"'), please refer to the row 460 with the picture below, I do search out the same row, it means the contains command works well with the keyword "644dbf5f0415", but I really don't know how "0412*" gives out the same result, it should not, because there isn't any word beginning with "0412"

Comment: please see the picture

Comment: d8c604bf-5162-44d5-b8fc-644dbf5f0415

Comment: @JiaWan Are you using [the Office Filter Packs](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/search/)? If so, then I retract my statement about how `CONTAINS` only supports textual columns.

Answer (score 2):

### Preface:

SQL Server's Full-Text Search engine comes with support for many binary (non-text) file-formats, including most Microsoft Office document formats (including the old `.doc`/`.xls` files, and the post-2007 OOXML+Zip-based `.docx`/`.xlsx` formats.

You can get a list of supported file-types (denoted by their filename extension rather than their MIME Content-Type, which I'd have preferred...) by running `select * from sys.fulltext_document_types;` against your server.

(If you're running on-prem SQL Server (*not* Azure SQL) you can install custom `IFilter` libraries to add support for additional file-types, [though Azure SQL is limited to first-party Microsoft-provided `IFilter` libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-fulltext-document-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)).

### The problem:

- You apparently have an Excel `.xlsx` (which is a **binary** file format) stored in a `varbinary(n)` column.
- The Excel file **is** indexed by SQL Server Full-Text Search:

  - Full-Text Search can read the file because it is able to use the `IFilter` library for Excel `.xlsx` files.
  - ... which is why the `CONTAINS` predicate function (and the `CONTAINSTABLE`, `FREETEXT`, and `FREETEXTTABLE` functions too, presumably) is able to succesfully and correctly return query results that show your Excel file contains that text.
  - ...but **your own application and query code** does not attempt to load or read the stored Excel `.xlsx` file *correctly* (i.e. by being-aware of the file-format and unpacking the OOXML `.zip` container, then reading the inner OOXML `.xml` files to go through the actual content-within).

    - Instead, your program simply naively assumes the `varbinary` content is somehow directly readable in SQL: **sorry, but it isn't**.
- ...but what (I think?) you want is to be able to show a *"highlighted extract"* from the Excel workbook that corresponds to the user's search terms found in the document (just like in Google/Bing Web Search results).

  - As it is, I can't suggest any *good solutions* to implement this feature in your application because we don't know how your application works, such as if it's even possible for your application-code to load, open, extract, and read/parse the OOXML files *at all* - or not.